# Trying to change featured image from 180x180 to full width on home page

Tags: php, theme-development, post-thumbnails, child-theme

Right now my theme puts a 180x180 square image to the left of the title on the home page for each blog post. I'd like to change that to be full width of the content area and below the title. I'm using a child theme, any ideas on how this would be done? Thanks!

Comment: Depends on the how the author setup the theme.  Some more specifics might help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Find the post thumbnail reference in your homepage template, or content-{single?}.php -whatever is generating the 180x180 image and change it to:

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail( 'full' , array('class' => 'home-page-thumbnail') ); ?>
```

and add the following to your style.css file:

```
.home-page-thumbnail { clear:both; }
```

Comment: thanks. It doesn't seem to work. I want it to display under the title tag. Any thoughts? Here is the site. [link]http://noahsdad.com